# jqueryui - if statement within button click callback

Tags: jquery-ui

Have I done something obviously obtuse, or is there a special format for evaluating `if()` conditions within a jqueryUI button callback?

```
$(function(){
    var focus_control = '';

    $( '#alert' ).dialog({
        autoOpen:false,
        show: 'fade',
        hide: 'fade',
        buttons: {
            Ok: function() {
                $(this).dialog('close');

                //Next line works if uncommented
                //$('#username').focus();

                //This if block breaks the js, but all works if this block commented out
                //var focus_control assigned elsewhere (ajax)
                if (focus_control=='staff_pick') {
                    $('#staff_pick').focus();
                }else if {focus_control=='username') {
                    $('#username').focus();
                }
            }
        }
    });
});
```

Is there a better way to rewrite this?  I tried:

```
                if (focus_control!='') {
                    $('#%focus_control%').focus();
                }
```

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do?

Comment: Upon closing dialog, set focus upon a particular input control based on the setting of the `focus_control` variable.

Comment: Do you have any JS console log? By the way the { in the else if block is a typo for this post, I hope :)

Comment: That typo would be the answer. Clearly your vision is better than mine. And I figured out my other question -- a momentary lapse of memory caused by not enough coding: `$('#'+focus_control).focus();`  SO... please put your typo discovery into an answer and I'll award the question to you. Again, my thanks.